# Looping through each cell, and if match, grab value and add to list/array which will like to use it for autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

Self explanatory subject. The problem I face now is that my `exrcif` is not increasing as I would like to include a list of criteria in the autofilter.

Currently I have this code:

```
    Dim oneCell as Range
    Dim exrcif as String

    For each oneCell in Range(“H2:H1000”)    
        With oneCell    
            If oneCell.value = 0 Then    
                exrcif = oneCell.Offset(,-7).Value    
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next oneCell

    Range(“A:H”).AutoFilter Field:=4, , Criteria1:=exrcif
End sub
```

Comment: Why the array list? Why don't you just filer by criteria column H = 0?

Comment: Oh i forgot to iterate, i did an offset there after finding the H= 0 to grab a value. Im using that value to do an autofilter.

Comment: The issue you have is that your `exrcif` is a `String`  and `exrcif = oneCell.Offset(,-7).Value` overwrites that string in each iteration. Instead you must add the value to an array (there are tutorials for how to add a value to an array, give it a try).

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that your `exrcif` is a `String` and no array and

```
exrcif = oneCell.Offset(,-7).Value
```

overwrites that string in each iteration. Instead you must append the value to an array:

For example write a procedure to append a value to an array

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AppendToArray(ByRef Arr() As Variant, ByVal AppendValue As Variant)
    Dim ArrSize As Long
    ArrSize = -1

    On Error Resume Next
    ArrSize = UBound(Arr)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim Preserve Arr(ArrSize + 1)
    Arr(ArrSize + 1) = AppendValue
End Sub
```

And use it like below

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim exrcif() As Variant

    Dim oneCell As Range
    For Each oneCell In Range("H2:H1000")
        If oneCell.Value = 0 Then
            AppendToArray Arr:=exrcif, AppendValue:=oneCell.Offset(, -7).Value
            'note no Exit For here! Otherwise it will stop after the first found 0
        End If
    Next oneCell

    Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=exrcif, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Peh, your code works wonder!! Have been figuring this around the forum for a day. Thanks alot for your help and have a great week ahead!

Answer (score 1):

variant using `Scripting.Dictionary`

```
Sub test()
    Dim oneCell As Range
    Dim exrcif As Object: Set exrcif = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each oneCell In Range("H2:H1000")
        With oneCell
            If oneCell.Value = 0 And _
                oneCell.Value <> "" And _
                Not exrcif.exists(oneCell.Offset(, -7).Value) Then
                exrcif.Add oneCell.Offset(, -7).Value, Nothing
            End If
        End With
    Next oneCell
    Range("A:H").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=exrcif.Keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

test:
[image]